# How to use function outside $scope ( error: function isn't defined)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rzslider which takes in true or false for disabled. I want disable to be true based on a function. So I want to make it `disabled:$scope.truthy`

I have a function called checkDupsName() checkDupsName should return true if there is a duplicate, false otherwise. I set my $scope.truthy variable to be true if the function returns true but the issue is, when I call it outside this function ( in my slider), it's ALWAYS false.

```
   $scope.checkDupsName = function(Mylist) {
                var i, j, n;
                n = Mylist.length;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                        if (Mylist[i] === Mylist[j]) {
                            return true;

                        }

                    }
                }

                return false;


            };

$scope.truthy=false;
  $scope.nameList = [];
  var Types = [];

   $scope.loadRuleList = function() {  



                PrioritizeService.getData($scope.prioritizeURL).
                then(function(response) {
                        if (response) {
                            Types = response;
                        }                              


                        for (var k = 0; k < Types.length; k++) {
                           $scope.nameList.push(Types[k].name);
                        } 



                        if($scope.checkDupsName($scope.nameList)) {
                          $scope.truthy=true;
                        }                     

            };

$scope.slider = {
                value: 1,
                options: {
                    floor: 0,
                    ceil: 3,
                    showTicks: true,
                    showTicksValues: true,
                    disabled:$scope.truthy

                }
            };
```

Comment: You are defining it inside of your function that is being called by `then`. You should move it outside and make it a function defined/declared on the `scope` instead and have it take the data it uses as a parameter.

Comment: So if I move it above the then, can I just pass in nameList as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You are defining it inside of your function that is being called by then. You should move it outside and make it a function defined/declared on the scope instead and have it take the data it uses as a parameter.

```
// initialize it so your code does not blow up in the case of forgotten undefined or null check
$scope.nameList = []; 

$scope.loadRuleList = function() {
    var me = this;
    PrioritizeService.getData($scope.MyURL).
    then(function(response) {

        if (response) {
            Types = response;    
        }                      

        // re-init the nameList field
        me.nameList = [];
        for (var k = 0; k < Types.length; k++) {
            me.nameList.push(Types[k].name)
        }
        //check for duplicates
        var areDups = me.checkDupsName(me.nameList);
    }
}

$scope.checkDupsName = function(listToCheck) {
    var i, j, n;
    n = listToCheck.length;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (listToCheck[i] === listToCheck[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }    
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: so what would I put in my slider now. disabled:$scope.checkDupsname(nameList)?

Comment: @Angular - You would still need to pass in a parameter unless your `$scope` also has a default array you want to always check. In that case alter my code above and use that instead. Is `nameList` a variable defined on `$scope`? It looks in your method that its a local variable declared in the `then` function.

Comment: I want to pass in nameList in the parameter. i can't just do that right because that's a local variable inside the checkDupsname function??

Comment: @Angular - correct. You could define it as a field on the $scope instead. Ill alter my example. Then it becomes `$scope.checkDupsname($scope.nameList)`. Your only remaining concern is making sure the code does not blow up if the field is null or undefined.

Comment: I get an error: vendor.js:11655 TypeError: $scope.checkDupsName is not a function

Comment: @Angular - I am not sure where you are calling it from. It could be that the $scope from your controller is not visible to your ?directive?. In which case that would be true. This last part has to do with how you have your html structured, specifically your controller and directives of interest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115151/discussion-between-angular-and-igor).