# Check for duplicates in array case-sensitive Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, underscore.js

My solution for checking if duplicates existed in an array using UnderscoreJS:

```
function hasDups(arr) {
   return arr.length !== _.uniq(arr).length;
}
```

This would work if the duplicate values were identical, but what about if one was in uppercase and the other was in lowercase? This `_.uniq` function wouldn't remove those kinds of duplicates.

Comment: so make a map and normalize the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can provide a function to uniq which will be used to transform elements:

```
function toLowerCase(s) {
    if (typeof(s) === 'string') {
        return s.toLowerCase();
    }

    return s;
}

function hasDups(arr) {
    return (arr.length !== _.uniq(arr, false, toLowerCase).length);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Reference: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like this in ES6

```js
var arr = ["Test", "test", "hello", "world"];
function checkDups(a) {
  b = Array.from(new Set(a.map(e => e.toLowerCase())));
  return a.length !== b.length;
}
console.log(checkDups(arr));
```

Comment: note you can simply compare lengths using [`Set.prototype.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) without having to create an `Array`

Comment: Well i  would be doubtful for safari,  enge and ie.

Comment: @Angular If you don't know what ES6 is, then you can just ignore this answer. The working assumption here is that people asking questions about JavaScript know about ES6; they might not know the details, or exactly what feature is supported in what browsers, but know how to figure those things out. Otherwise, every single question giving an ES6 answer would have to provide a lengthy disclaimer about what browsers it might not work in, or describe what it does, or point to support tables. I strongly suggest you bone up quickly on ES6 basics--it's the future of our profession.

Comment: @torazaburo ok thanks man. can you maybe look at this question I posted 2 days ago, but it's still not working. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931285/how-to-use-function-outside-scope-error-function-isnt-defined